# Counting Methods declaration + Methods Calls in a class using JavaParser

Tags: java, parsing, methods, javaparser

I'm trying to code rfc metric (Response for a Class), it counts the Method declarations + Method Calls.

Method declarations works fine, but I got a problem at counting method calls using JavaParser API.

Here is my code:

```
public class MethodPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D://test.java");
        CompilationUnit cu;
        try {
            // parse the file
            cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        // visit and print the methods names
        MethodVisitor MV =new MethodVisitor();

        cu.accept(new VoidVisitorAdapter<Void>(){
            @Override
            public void visit(final MethodCallExpr n, final Void arg){
                System.out.println("method call :"+n);
                super.visit(n, arg);

            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

test.java

```
package test;
import java.util.*;

public class ClassA 
{
  private int test;
  private ClassB classB = new ClassB();
  public void doSomething(int t){

    System.out.println ( toString());
    int i= doSomethingBasedOnClassBBV(classB.toString());
  }
  protected void doSomethingBasedOnClassB(){
    System.out.println (classB.toString());
  }
}

public class ClassB 
{
  private ClassA classA = new ClassA();
  public void doSomethingBasedOneClassA(){
    System.out.println (classA.toString());
  }

  private String toString(){
    return "classB";
  }
  private String toString(){
    return "classB";
  }
  public void doSomethingBasedOneClassA(){
    System.out.println (classA.toString());
  }
  protected void doSomethingBasedOnClassB(){
    System.out.println (classB.toString());
  }
}
```

the result of that code:

```
*method call :System.out.println(toString())

method call :toString()

method call :doSomethingBasedOnClassBBV(classB.toString())

method call :classB.toString()

method call :System.out.println(classB.toString())

method call :classB.toString()

method call :System.out.println(classA.toString())

method call :classA.toString()

method call :System.out.println(classA.toString())

method call :classA.toString()

method call :System.out.println(classB.toString())

method call :classB.toString()*
```

indeed, that code inspects method calls, but in my case I don't want it to count libraries method calls like System.out.println`(toString())`, I want it to count only `toString()`.

If you got a better code, or another API to use... any help is welcomed, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily resolve your issue using exclusively a parser, because you need to resolve the method call and find out if it is a call to a method part of the standard library.

You can easily do that using [JavaSymbolSolver](https://github.com/javaparser/javasymbolsolver), which is a library created to complement JavaParser. In practice you call:

`JavaParserFacade.solveMethodAsUsage(myMethodCallExpr)`

And you get back a MethodDeclaration which tells you also the type on which that method was defined. Once you have the type you can look at the package and check if it starts with `java` or `javax` and exclude it.

Comment: This a classic example of why Life After Parsing is important when building any kind of static analysis tools.  See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html